# Get data from another excel file using data in a cell

Tags: excel

I don't know if a formula exist for my needs, but here's what I need to do.

I have 2 Excels files.

1. One with a **list of services** with several data. The name of the company offering the service is there. The name of the file : **sevices.xlsx**
2. One with the **list of the companies** with complete contact infos (address, phone number, name of the contact person...) The name of the file : **companies.xlsx**

**I need to get the name of the contact person listed in companies.xlsx added *dynamically* into my services.xlsx file.** The goal here is to have to update only one file instead of two.

So I want to use the **name of the company** in the column **"L" of my services.xlsx** file to get the same company name listed in the **"A" column of the companies.xlsx** file, then get the value of the **contact person** on column **"G" from the companies.xlsx** to show in the column **"M" from my services.xlsx file**.

Is there a formula for this ? 
I looked at INDIRECT formula, but it seems I can only use cell number, which I don't know.

Comment: The LOOKUP and MATCH functions work across workbooks. Assuming the data in companies.xlsx is organized by columns, and the column with the contact person is to the right of the column with the company name, you should be able to use VLOOKUP.

Comment: Vlookup worked!! Thanks !!